# What does " yarn build " command do? Are " npm build " and "yarn build" similar commands?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

What does `yarn build` command do ? 
Are `yarn build` and `npm build` the same? If not what's the difference?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`yarn build` and `npm build` are not existing commands by default. I think you mean `yarn run build` or `npm run build`.

`build` is a command which can be specified in your `package.json` file on the `scripts` property. See the example below.

```
{
    "name": "mypackage",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "scripts": {
       "build": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js"
    }
}
```

In this example, `build` is a shortcut for launching command `webpack --config webpack.dev.js`. You can use every keyword you want to define some shortcuts to launch commands.

And the only difference between the two commands it's the JS dependency manager you're using, yarn or npm.

More infos :

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/

https://www.npmjs.com/

Comment: where I can find the bundled app?

Comment: after yarn build you can see the build folder inside your project, this folder contains the bundled app or compiled project.

Comment: Although I can't find it documented anywhere, I just ran `yarn build`, and it does work; it's perfectly valid shorthand for `yarn run build`.

Comment: `yarn build` works perfectly fine just like `yarn run build`, same is with `yarn dev` that also works fine just like `yarn run dev`, Although this is not mentioned at any place but they just works.

Answer (score 7):

"yarn build
Bundles the app into static files for production." from Create React App by MAD9135.

https://mad9135.github.io/F2020/modules/week3/02-react-tooling/07-create-react-app.html

Comment: Where did you read this? For me `yarn` does not understand such command.

Comment: It's apparently the output of [some command](https://mad9135.github.io/F2020/modules/week3/02-react-tooling/07-create-react-app.html). Also, please don't quote without telling where you got the quote.

Answer (score 6):

`yarn build` is a shortcut of `yarn run build`
from original documentation:

[image: yarn documentation screenshot]

Reference: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/#toc-yarn-run-script

Answer (score 1):

its the same i guess the real difference between yarn and npm is the performance and security that yarn provides.

yarn actually installing packages in parallelly and Npm only install one package at a time

And Yarn have more secure dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Yarn is a package manager for your code. Yarn build makes a bundle of apps in one format and shows errors if the app has any problem that will make an error on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Note that while using [yarn.build](https://yarn.build/), a `yarn.build` key within package.json will be used by `yarn build` from the root workspace and `yarn run build` is required to run a locally defined `scripts: { build: ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn can also install packages from the local cache