# How can remove the port number from live vue site url?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, port, javascript-framework

while running the `yarn serve` I don't what to display the port no from the URL. Now, this is showing like https://example.com:8080. I want to access them from https://example.com.

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
      config.plugins.delete('prefetch');
    },
    devServer: {
        host: 'example.com',
        https: false,
        port: 8080, 
        public: 'example.com'
    }, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `yarn serve` command opens this port to serve the app locally (for testing / developing).

If you want to create your application, you probably want to run:
`yarn run build`

See [SO - yarn build command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54693442/10441671)

You can then upload the generated files. Look for a `build` or `dist` directory or similar.

You can add `publicPath` to your configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
    publicPath: "./",
    chainWebpack: config => {
      config.plugins.delete('prefetch');
    },
    devServer: {
        host: 'example.com',
        https: false,
        port: 8080, 
        public: 'example.com'
    }, 
}
```

You can try this and see if it works.

See [webpack configuration docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#automatic-publicpath)

Comment: I tried that but after run yarn run build I got 'dist' folder if I run the index,html file I am getting the white blank page.

Comment: Yes correct, the `dist` folder has the app then. What error do you get in the browser console?

Comment: GET https://example.us/css/app.c52c71c3.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
example.us/:14 GET https://example.us/css/chunk-vendors.552a1056.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
example.us/:14 GET https://example.us/js/app.8b633902.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):12 GET https://example.us/styles/_fontawesome.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
example.us/:14 GET https://example.us/js/chunk-vendors.8b9cfb1c.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
example.us/:14 GET https://example.us/js/app.8b633902.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I am getting errors like this.

Comment: You configured `example.us` as the domain for the application. That is why it is trying to read the files from there. Don't use `example.us`. The domain name is an example and you are supposed to replace it with your own - or stay with relative file names.

Comment: I have replaced but still showing the white blank. also the file user should dist/css/app.c52c71c3.css but they are  like this /css/app.c52c71c3.css

Comment: This means the base path of the app is probably incorrect. You can share the webpack configuration etc. if you want. I would suggest you create an example application with default settings and learn how it is configured there.

Comment: `module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
      config.plugins.delete('prefetch');
    },
    devServer: {
  host: 'example.com',
  https: false,
  port: 8080, 
  public: 'example.com'
    },
 }`

Comment: Please update your original post with the configuration. It is unreadable as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: updated in main post.

Comment: Okay thanks, that's better. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the index.html in the dist folder with live server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).